# Как реализовать обобщенный интерфейс

Tags: c#, generics

Мне в интерфейсе нужно определить обобщенный список, а потом в классах его реализовать. Как это сделать?

```
interface IData
{
    List<object> Data { get; set; }
    // List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

class MyClass : IData
{
    public List<object> Data { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Data = new List<Cats>(); // ???
    }
}

class Cats
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `interface IData<T>`, и еще вот эту статью почитайте [Ковариация и контравариация в универсальных шаблонах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Опишите generic-интерфейс:

```
interface IData<T>
{
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

class MyClass : IData<Cats>
{
    public List<Cats> Data { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Data = new List<Cats>(); 
    }
}

class Cats
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kwtft8ak.aspx)

Comment: А как потом узнать тип переменной, реализующий интерфейс? [Вот здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467980/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81) подробное описание вопроса.