# Как узнать тип переменной, реализующий обобщенный интерфейс

Tags: c#

Как узнать тип переменной, реализующий обобщенный интерфейс? (В продолжении [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467931/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81/467934))

```
namespace InterfaceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FormImitation form = new FormImitation();
            form.DataWork = new MyClass();
            form.Calculate();
        }        
    }

    class FormImitation
    {
        public IDataBase DataWork { get; set; }

        public void Calculate()
        {
            ((IDataBase)DataWork).Run();
            ((IData<???>)DataWork).Data = null; // ???
        }
    }

    interface IDataBase
    {
        void Run();
    }

    interface IData<T> : IDataBase
    {
        List<T> Data { get; set; }        
    }

    class MyClass : IData<Cats>
    {
        public List<Cats> Data { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            Data = new List<Cats>();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
        }
    }

    class Cats
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [typeof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/58918ffs.aspx)? а вообще Вы можете сами наложить определенные ограничения на T, т.е. сделать так что `T` будет например только ссылочный тип, или тип значения ну и т.п.

Comment: По поводу `((IDataBase)DataWork).Run();`: переменная `DataWork` у вас и так объявлена как `IDataBase` - зачем приводить ещё раз к этому же типу? Достаточно написать `DataWork.Run();`.

Comment: По поводу `((IData<???>)DataWork).Data = null;`: по-моему, этот код должен быть не в `FormImitation`, потому что в `FormImitation` идёт работа с абстракцией `IDataBase`.

Comment: Можно, например, в интерфейс `IDataBase` добавить метод `Flush()`, реализация которого в `MyClass` будет таковой: `public void Flush() { Data = null; }`. Опять-таки без всяких приведений типов.

Comment: @Regent Да, согласен, можно не приводить тип. А как тогда определить в FormImitation свойство _public **IData** DataWork { get; set; }_? А метод Flush, наверно, не очень подходит - здесь для примера Data только обнуляется.

Comment: Назовите этот метод по-другому - право ваше. Если нужно в этом методе делать что-то другое - в классе `MyClass` вы сможете это сделать без каких-либо проблем и приведений. Если в `FormImitation` по какой-то причине нужно объявлять `DataWork` именно как `IData<T>`, то тут не знаю как можно это сделать. Подозреваю, что просто объявить `public IData<T> DataWork { get; set; }` нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вам нужно определиться, какой именно код вы хотите выполнить. Приглядитесь к этой строке:

```
((IData<???>)DataWork).Data = null;
```

Вы хотите присвоить `null`. Если это единственное, что вам нужно сделать, то решение простое: реализовать необобщённый интерфейс с методом `RemoveData`:

```
((IDataBase)DataWork).Data = null;

interface IDataBase
{
    // ...
    void RemoveData ();
}

class MyClass : IData<Cats>
{
    // ...
    public void RemoveData ()
    {
        Data = null;
    }
}
```

Однако, скорее всего, вам нужно не только уничтожать данные, но и добавлять, и тогда ваша строчка преобразуется в это:

```
((IData<???>)DataWork).Data = new List<???> { new ??? { ??? } };
```

Замечаете проблему? Вы хотите создать что-то, о чём вы не имеете никакого представления. Единственное, что вы знаете наверняка — это что нужно создать список чего-то. Очевидно, этой информации недостаточно для того, чтобы создать и заполнить список "чего-то".

Почему это происходит? Потому что классу `FormImitation`, который работает с данными `MyClass`, почему-то не предоставляется информации о том, с чем он должен работать. Это всё равно что закидывать ему `object` и ожидать, что он угадает интерфейсы и методы.

И здесь возникают варианты:

1. Если вы хотите, чтобы класс `FormImitation` работал с любыми типами данных, то он должен быть обобщённым. И передавать в этот класс нужно обобщённый `IData<T>`, а не его предка `IDataBase`.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main ()
       {
           var form = new FormImitation<Cats>();
           form.DataWork = new MyClass();
           form.Calculate();
       }
   }

   class FormImitation<T>
   {
       public IData<T> DataWork { get; set; }

       public void Calculate ()
       {
           DataWork.Run();
           DataWork.Data = null; // !!!
       }
   }
   ```
2. Если `FormImitation` должен работать с любыми типами данных и переключаться между ними, то, скорее всего, вы докатитесь до отражений. Однако конкретно в вашем случае можно обойтись добавлением в необобщённый `IDataBase` списка базового типа.

   ```
   class FormImitation
   {
       public IDataBase DataWork { get; set; }

       public void Calculate ()
       {
           DataWork.Run();
           DataWork.Data = null; // !!!
       }
   }

   interface IDataBase
   {
       void Run ();
       IList Data { get; set; }
   }

   interface IData<T> : IDataBase
   {
       new IList<T> Data { get; set; }
   }

   class MyClass : IData<Cats>
   {
       public List<Cats> Data { get; set; }

       IList<Cats> IData<Cats>.Data
       {
           get { return Data; }
           set { Data = (List<Cats>)value; }
       }

       IList IDataBase.Data
       {
           get { return Data; }
           set { Data = (List<Cats>)value; }
       }

       public MyClass ()
       {
           Data = new List<Cats>();
       }

       public void Run () { }
   }
   ```

   Два грубых приведения типа не позволят вам сделать чего-либо полезного с этим кодом, но работать он будет. Если вы засунете не тот тип в свойство `Data`, то ошибка вылетит во время выполнения, а не при компиляции.
3. Ещё можно нашаманить с отражениями и динамическими типами, но я не буду учить вас плохому.

А теперь, когда у нас есть, как минимум, три решения, надо понять одно: **они все неправильные**.

1. Выставление списка в виде `List<T> Data { get; set; }` — это нарушение инкапсуляции.

   1. Во-первых, потому что вы заставляете реализацию использовать конкретный тип коллекции. Следует выбрать `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` или `IList<T>` в зависимости от реальных потребностей.
   2. Во-вторых, потому что вы можете подсунуть обладателю коллекции любую коллекцию. Сеттеров на свойствах коллекций быть не должно, лучше сделать read-only свойство, и при необходимости очищать коллекцию.
   3. В-третьих, положив в свойство `null`, вы с большой долей вероятности получите `NullReferenceException` где-нибудь в коде. Следует использовать пустые объекты (пустой список в данном случае), а не `null`.
2. Логика изменения данных размазана по всем классам: в `Main` вы создаёте "базу данных", "база данных" сама создаёт список данных, потом интерфейсная прослойка эти данные уничтожает.

В общем и целом, вам надо хорошо подумать над архитектурой и определиться с ролями каждого класса.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Уточнение: пусть будет только один интерфейс IData, содержащий только методы. IData и FormImitation пусть будут не обобщенными. Тогда из FormImitation можно вызывать методы интерфейса, a список List<Cats> будет меняться методами внутри MyClass (несколько кнопок на форме, каждая вызывает какой-то метод интерфейса, меняя List<Cats>). Но так как FormImitation - форма, то как ей получить List<Cats> для заполнения, например, ListView?

Comment: Нужен метод в интерфейсе, возвращающий List<T> - тогда опять возникает те же проблемы; или нужен метод в интерфейсе, принимающий Windows.Forms.ListView формы, что тоже, скорее всего, не правильно?

Comment: @egeo Зачем вам метод, возвращающий *именно этот тип* коллекции?